# Reheating bishul Akum

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, bishul-akum

Pardon me while I try to construct the right hypothetical:

I was invited to a [state dinner](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43386/bishul-akum-state-dinners) recently. I brushed off the tux and polished my shoes and called up to make sure that the administration had hired a mashgiach whom I trust. I was assured that the mashigiach would be present and everything would be on the up and up.

When I sat down, and had my first course delivered (a lovely fancy, cooked dish) the mashgiach came over to me and said, "I didn't turn the oven on! This food is bishul akum!"

So I went through the check list of all the exclusions for bishul akum and found none - my meal was completely bishul akum. So sad...it looked nice. [note - for the sake of the hypothetical, please avoid finding reasons that the food is not bishul akum]

Can bishul akum food be taken home and reheated? I don't fully understand if the food is inherently not kosher (the [ambiguity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/bishul-akum-now-what) over kashering dishes doesn't help and leaves the question of whether one would have to kasher the dishes it was served on, not just cooked in) and whether reheating is part of the cooking "process" at the opposite end from turning on the stove which would turn it acceptable. Would it matter if the food cooled down all the way?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59797/1362) question looks at the question of the non-Jew "cooking" after the Jew but not the reverse.

Comment: Given "ein bishul achar bishul" it won't help. What acts as a leniency on Shabbat is a stringency here.

Comment: So let me get this straight: You're going to turn to your waiter at a state dinner and ask for a doggie bag?

Comment: Reheating doesn't help. If, however, the food were under-cooked, that might be something. That doesn't seem likely at a state dinner.

Comment: @CashCow We hold that there CAN be bishul achar bishul in many cases, which is why reheating water, soup, etc. is problematic. Mitztamek viyafeh/ra lo, as well, provides an avenue for viewing "additional cooking" as an independent action that can change the status of the food...

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%98

Comment: @IsaacMoses I stopped having doggie bag shame many years ago

Comment: is the point of the Y"D to distinguish between ben drosai and uncooked or ben drosai and fully cooked? @DoubleAA

Comment: If a non Jew cooked it all the way, then a Jew continuing wouldn't help, unlike if a Jew finished it from MBD. See Maharsha there for instance for someone explicit. Most others probably just assume it.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have to check inside but is there a difference between "continuing after it is fully cooked" and reheating from cold?

Comment: TTBOMK no. Again, this may be something that's hard to find explicit in a classical source. It's just assumed.

Comment: @DoubleAA halacha vav reads "כל שבישלו ישראל מעט בישולו בין בתחלה בין בסוף מותר" the sof there seems to contradict "וגמרו ישראל יש לאסור".

Comment: @Danno The Mechaber must read "basof" to be the end of the MBD cooking, I'd think.

Answer (score 2):

The late Rabbi Salzer of the Adath Jeshurun community in Johannesburg (paying attention Danny Schoeman?) gave a strange ruling.  He paskened that potato chips were bishul akum and he advised members of his kehillah to cover them with ketchup and reheat them in the oven.  I never understood this.  If the chips were bishul akum then putting them into the oven would make the oven traif.  Nevertheless, this is how he paskened.  Applying this to your question, I would assume that doing something to enhance or simply change the food you brought home from the State dinner would then permit it.

Comment: What you've described is actually cooking a new (unappealing IMO) dish. As such, taken with Loewian's answer, this might make sense, although I will readily admit that I've learned very few of hilchot bishul akum.

Comment: Sounds like all you need to do is put some salt on it, no?

Comment: @DanF And cook it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that reheating is allowed on Shabbath (provided it is in a manner that doesn't run into Rabbinic restrictions like *shehiyah* or *hachzara*) because it is not considered cooking, it logically follows that reheating should not uproot a *bishul akum* status (anymore than would the food cooling off after having been cooked). The only place where one could entertain introducing a leniency would be where the food truly reverted to its original, uncooked state (which, by *hilchot shabbat* is a potential concern by liquids such as water) but if indeed the cooling off does regain the food a permitted status, reheating it again would not be the catalyst of that change. This is also the reasoning in the reverse case you link since the issue is who originally rendered it fit for consumption.

Comment: But some think Ein Bishul Achar Bishul does _not_ apply to meat+milk, for example. Your claim about the breadth of its application is not trivial.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting point. Do you mind sharing the source? (I assume also you mean where the meat and milk were already cooked together in the original *bishul* and we're only talking about reheating?; also, "some think" implies others do not - so my reasoning would work according to the others.

Comment: See RAEiger and Gilyon Maharsha at the very beginning of YD 87 http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4212 Re "some think" your reasoning _could_ work. There's still nothing saying it _does_ work.